# Julia 0.4.0-dev+7053 html parsing is extremely fast

Tags: html, web-scraping, julia

Edit: 
... well, became fast after the gracious help by @Ismael VC. The solution was wiping my Julia v0.4 first, reinstalling it from the most recent nightly, and then a certain amount of package juggling: `Pkg.init()`, `Pkg.add("Gumbo")`. This addition of Gumbo produces a build error at first:

```
INFO: Installing Gumbo v0.1.0
INFO: Building Gumbo

WARNING: deprecated syntax "[a=>b, ...]" at /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/Gumbo/deps/build.jl:19.
Use "Dict(a=>b, ...)" instead.
INFO: Attempting to Create directory /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/Gumbo/deps/downloads
INFO: Downloading file http://jamesporter.me/static/julia/gumbo-1.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
================================[ ERROR: Gumbo ]================================

LoadError: failed process: Process(`curl -f -o /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/Gumbo/deps/downloads/gumbo-1.0.tar.gz -L http://jamesporter.me/static/julia/gumbo-1.0.tar.gz`, ProcessExited(22)) [22]
while loading /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4/Gumbo/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 19

================================================================================

================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: Gumbo had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in /Users/szalmaf/.julia/v0.4
 - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("Gumbo")`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

================================================================================
INFO: Package database updated
```

, so one needs to check out the latest Gumbo from the master branch `Pkg.update()`, `Pkg.build("Gumbo")`, which in turn produces a Gumbo whose `parsehtml` is blazing fast.

Note: the problem was not what gets mentioned by a commenter (who did not read previous comments carefully enough), namely, the claim that the JIT compiler makes 'it' slow. If you read the back and forth discussion between me and @Ismael VC, you can see that I ran his exact test code as he did and I got the results in the first two of my comments, which with my original installation was indeed too slow. Anyway, the important thing is that `parsehtml` is as fast as it gets with Ismael's help in our private chat. Thanks again!

---

Original post:

Julia 0.4.0-dev+7053 html parsing is extremely slow?

Though the Julia language is being sold as fast at many things, it looks very slow at basic things of life like parsing web pages.

Profiling the `http://julialang.org` web page, which shows how fast Julia is against C, Fortran, R, Matlab, etc.

```
# using HTTPClient, Gumbo
julia_url = "http://julialang.org"
println("  scrape start: ", Dates.unix2datetime(time()))
julia_pageg = julia_url |> get
println("  scrape end: ", Dates.unix2datetime(time()))
julia_page = julia_pageg |> x->x.body |> bytestring |> parsehtml
println("  parsed: ", Dates.unix2datetime(time()))
```

gives

```
scrape start: 2015-09-05T16:47:03.843
scrape end: 2015-09-05T16:47:04.044
parsed: 2015-09-05T16:47:04.41
```

which shows that getting this webpage takes ~100ms, which is reasonable over my wifi connection, however, parsing this simple page takes ~400ms, which sounds prohibitive by today's standards.

Doing the same test for a somewhat more complex webpage

```
julia_url = "http://www.quora.com/How-powerful-and-faster-is-Julia-Language"
println("  scrape start: ", Dates.unix2datetime(time()))
julia_pageg = julia_url |> get
println("  scrape end: ", Dates.unix2datetime(time()))
julia_page = julia_pageg |> x->x.body |> bytestring |> parsehtml
println("  parsed: ", Dates.unix2datetime(time()))
```

gives

```
scrape start: 2015-09-05T16:57:52.054
scrape end: 2015-09-05T16:57:52.736
parsed: 2015-09-05T16:57:53.699
```

where parsing takes almost a full second.

I am probably missing something, but is there a better/faster way in Julia of parsing a webpage or getting an html element out of it? If so, how?

Comment: The biggest time sink here is compilation time (the JIT on first run).  When I run it a second time in the same julia process, my times are 10x and 100x faster, respectively.

Comment: The timings I give above are all at least on the second run so there is no interference with JIT compilation. If you scrape 1000 websites in a loop, the compilation time is not noticeable anyway. Could you share the times you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, have you red the performance tips in te manual? Which Julia version are you using? (`versioninfo()`)

- http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/

You could start by reading that, and putting your code inside a function as suggested in the documentation, there is an `@time` macro, that also hints you about memory allocation, something like this:

## Julia v0.3.11

Tested at: https://juliabox.org

```
using HTTPClient, Gumbo

function test(url::String)
    @show url

    print("Scraping: ")
    @time page = get(url)

    print("Parsing: ")
    @time page = parsehtml(bytestring(page.body))
end

let
    gc_disable()

    url =  "http://julialang.org"

    println("First run:")
    test(url)    # first run JITed

    println("\nSecond run:")
    test(url)

    url = "http://www.quora.com/How-powerful-and-faster-is-Julia-Language"    

    println("\nThird run:")
    test(url)

    println("\nFourth run:")
    test(url)

    gc_enable()
end
```

---

```
First run:
url => "http://julialang.org"
Scraping: elapsed time: 0.248092469 seconds (3971912 bytes allocated)
Parsing: elapsed time: 0.850927483 seconds (27207516 bytes allocated)

Second run:
url => "http://julialang.org"
Scraping: elapsed time: 0.055722638 seconds (73952 bytes allocated)
Parsing: elapsed time: 0.005446998 seconds (821800 bytes allocated)

Third run:
url => "http://www.quora.com/How-powerful-and-faster-is-Julia-Language"
Scraping: elapsed time: 0.282382774 seconds (619324 bytes allocated)
Parsing: elapsed time: 0.227427243 seconds (9728620 bytes allocated)

Fourth run:
url => "http://www.quora.com/How-powerful-and-faster-is-Julia-Language"
Scraping: elapsed time: 0.288903961 seconds (400272 bytes allocated)
Parsing: elapsed time: 0.017787089 seconds (1516560 bytes allocated)
```

### This are the timings of your code with `@time`:

```
julia_url = "http://julialang.org"
@time julia_pageg = julia_url |> get
@time julia_page = julia_pageg |> x->x.body |> bytestring |> parsehtml
```

First run:

```
elapsed time: 0.361194892 seconds (11108960 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.996812988 seconds (34546156 bytes allocated, 4.04% gc time)
```

Second run:

```
elapsed time: 0.018920084 seconds (77952 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.006632215 seconds (823256 bytes allocated)
```

---

```
julia_url = "http://www.quora.com/How-powerful-and-faster-is-Julia-Language"
@time julia_pageg = julia_url |> get
@time julia_page = julia_pageg |> x->x.body |> bytestring |> parsehtml
```

First run:

```
elapsed time: 0.33795947 seconds (535916 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.224386491 seconds (9729852 bytes allocated)
```

Second run:

```
elapsed time: 0.276848452 seconds (584944 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.018806686 seconds (1517856 bytes allocated)
```

## Edit v0.4.0-dev+7053

In version 0.4+ make sure to first do a `Pkg.checkout("Gumbo")` in order to pull the latest commits, after doing that and then doing a `Pkg.build("Gumbo")` in JuliaBox I get:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Ismael-VC/4c241228f04ed54c70e2

```
First run:
url = "http://julialang.org"
Scraping:   0.227681 seconds (85.11 k allocations: 3.585 MB)
Parsing:   0.696063 seconds (799.12 k allocations: 29.450 MB)

Second run:
url = "http://julialang.org"
Scraping:   0.018953 seconds (571 allocations: 69.344 KB)
Parsing:   0.007132 seconds (15.91 k allocations: 916.313 KB)

Third run:
url = "http://www.quora.com/How-powerful-and-faster-is-Julia-Language"
Scraping:   0.313128 seconds (4.86 k allocations: 608.850 KB)
Parsing:   0.196110 seconds (270.17 k allocations: 10.356 MB)

Fourth run:
url = "http://www.quora.com/How-powerful-and-faster-is-Julia-Language"
Scraping:  0.307949 seconds (1.41 k allocations: 470.953 KB)
Parsing:   0.019801 seconds (23.82 k allocations: 1.627 MB)
```

Comment: Running your code gives me                                                           `Scraping:   0.508637 seconds (1.65 k allocations: 592.828 KB, 0.44% gc time)
Parsing:   0.907967 seconds (127.34 k allocations: 1023.643 MB, 5.49% gc time)
Scraping:   0.547456 seconds (1.64 k allocations: 408.063 KB)
Parsing:   0.880006 seconds (127.31 k allocations: 1023.645 MB, 5.33% gc time)`.

Comment: Running it for the second time so to avoid JIT caused slow-down gives me `Scraping:   0.420002 seconds (1.54 k allocations: 587.125 KB)
Parsing:   0.921989 seconds (127.34 k allocations: 1023.643 MB, 5.61% gc time)
Scraping:   0.424703 seconds (1.58 k allocations: 589.406 KB)
Parsing:   0.975493 seconds (127.31 k allocations: 1023.645 MB, 5.73% gc time)`

Comment: If you carefully look at the above two outputs of your code, you can see there is hardly any difference (actually, the second one is worse!). So I don't understand your point. Would you mind elaborating? Sure I put my code into functions and tried to speed it up in many ways based on performance tips in the Julia manual and other sources I just found. But no success.

Comment: `versioninfo()` gives `Julia Version 0.4.0-pre+7316
Commit 86a2a31 (2015-09-05 20:44 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Darwin (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3`

Comment: @szf I'm sorry I've been slow to complete my answer, since I was on my smartphone, I have edited the answer and included the output. Test are run at JuliaBox with Julia `v0.3.11`

Comment: @szf I don't know if this is good enough for you, but either way you where testing it wrongly, you can also test this at JuliaBox, for a more even comparison, gc pressure is something to also take into account.

Comment: @Ismail VC You are claiming that my test is wrong. But you are not telling me where it is wrong? I just did the same as you using your own code.

Comment: @Ismail VC But it seems like the Julia v0.4-pre is giving me the slowness for some reason. I have been using v0.4, but now I reverted back to v0.3.10 just to try your test and I am getting times similar to yours.

Comment: @szf I've updated the answer again, with your code timings running at the global scope, you can see that your method of testing it is slower, since you didn't follow the performance tips. As I said I don't know if the speed of these tests are good enough for your purposes, but it's a fact that you where testing wrongly. Keep in mind that v0.4+ is the development version, and as such it's unstable. Also when refering to the current development version you must indicate the version+commit count in your reports, ie: `0.4.0-dev+7053` (current dev JuliaBox version)

Comment: @Ismail VC So can you update your answer again now with the second run timings for my code because that makes it a fair comparison since all my timings are second or later run timings?

Comment: @szf It's done! Be sure to run this tests more thatn a few times though in order to get a representative sample, you could even plot your results.

Comment: @Ismail So now I hope that you can also see it for yourself that in this case it did not matter what you claimed that the commands needed to be in a function. Sure, that is true in general, but not in this case. Please make sure before you suggest something obvious or suggest a test has been done 'wrongly', check your claims twice!

Comment: @Ismail I am actually here to understand why the 0.4-pre version of Julia has this slowness problem and how to remedy that for now. If you can help me with that it'd actually be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88938/discussion-between-ismael-vc-and-szf).

Comment: Sfz, it looks like you are restarting Julia between timings.  Every time you restart, Julia will JIT compile the code again. If you, instead, run both sets of timings at the REPL or in IJulia, you should see similar timings to @Ismael VC.